# How to rename the name of 64base image uploaded to Cloudinary

Tags: node.js, base64, cloudinary

In this code I am uploading 64base image to cloudinary
How can I change the name of the uploaded image ?
here is my Nodejs Code:

```
 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(`data:image/png;base64,${req.body.image}`,
            function (error, result) { console.log(result, error); });
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the public_id to the request-https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#public_id_the_image_identifier